# Pass timestamp between Powerbuilder datawindow and SQLServer insert/update stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, casting, timestamp, powerbuilder

can anyone help me out.

By implementing countermeasures in solving the concurrency problem I got troubled with passing timestamps (rowversion) between Powerbuilder 7 datawindow and SQLServer 2008 (both ways) using insert and update stored procedures.

The connection is serviced by ODBC, not native. Most of my attempts result in casting poblems (convert). What to do?

Tnx

Comment: It's the database's job to manage transactions. It sounds like you may be using the wrong approach to your problem. What is the concurrency problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hi, the concurrency problem Itry to resolve is related to a multi-user environment. When person A selects a record an person B selects the same and both persons modify for example the same attribute with different values, then it is not sure witch value is the right one. 

When using a timestamp one can prevent the last updator to save his modification by verifying the selected timestamp with the one in the database. My problem is transfering the timestamp right between Powerbuilder and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a timestamp, just use an integer. The update stored procedure will then accept this as one of it's parameters and compare it against the one in the database. If they don't match, you can report back that "this record has been updated by another user, you will need to retrieve it before you can make further changes", if they do match, the update procedure just increments the version as part of the record update.